# Child Component not rendered in react js

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

I have a situation here where I cannot render my child component ModalConatiner from my parent. I would however like to mention that there is a chain of parent child components before and after this piece.I have imported it as well.

```
 getAssetDocId(e) {
        var assetDocId = e.currentTarget.attributes['id'].value;
        var assetDBId = e.currentTarget.attributes['dbId'].value;
        var code = e.currentTarget.attributes['code'].value;

        console.log('----------------------------------------------------');
        return <ModalContainer assetDocId={assetDocId} assetDBId={assetDBId} code={code} defaultValues={this.props.defaultValues} allAssetDetails={this.props.allAssetDetails} />
     }
```

called by

```
<div className="card-overlay modal-trigger"  data-target="asset-detail" id={asset.docId} dbId={asset.dbId} code={asset.code} key={asset.docId} onClick={this.getAssetDocId}>
```

The child component -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button, Icon, Row, Col, Carousel, Chip, Collapsible, CollapsibleItem, Input, Dropdown, NavItem, Form, Modal} from 'react-materialize';
import AssetDetails from './../assetlisting/assetdetails.jsx';

class ModalContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.resetValues = this.resetValues.bind(this);
        this.resetAssetValues = React.createRef();
        this.renderAssetDetails = this.renderAssetDetails.bind(this);
    }

    renderAssetDetails() {

        return <AssetDetails assetDocId={this.props.assetDocId} assetDBId={this.props.assetDBId} code={this.props.code} defaultValues = {this.props.defaultValues} ref={this.resetAssetValues} allAssetDetails={this.props.allAssetDetails}/>;
    }

    resetValues = () => {
        this.resetAssetValues.current.showInfo();
    };

    render() {
        console.log('ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp');

        return (
            <div>
                <Modal id="asset-detail" className="fullscreen"
                       modalOptions={{preventScrolling: true}}>
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="asset-details">
                            <div className="modal-close waves-effect" onClick={this.resetValues}>
                                <i className="material-icons">close</i>
                            </div>
                            { this.renderAssetDetails() }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ModalContainer;
```

Can somebody please point out what is the issue here?

Comment: onClick={(e) => this.getAssetDocId(e)}>

Comment: @LazarNikolic It still doesn't work.I think there is some issue with the child component not being rendered.

Comment: Do you get ----------- in console?

Comment: Yes I do get it

Comment: Do you want to have a look at the MOdalContainer component? @LazarNikolic

Comment: Yes please. You can edit your question by adding the code for that component as well.

Comment: Do you receive ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp in the console?

Comment: nope @AdityaChawla i did not

Comment: @LazarNikolic Added the child component as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to render child component is

Check below code for better understanding. This is how you can implement your functionality

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      assetDocId: "",
      assetDBId: "",
      code: "",
      showModalContainer: false
   }
}

getAssetDocId = e => {
     this.setState({
        assetDocId:e.currentTarget.attributes['id'].value,
        assetDBId: e.currentTarget.attributes['dbId'].value,
        code: e.currentTarget.attributes['code'].value,
        showModalContainer: true
     })
}

render(){
    const {assetDocId, assetDBId, code, showModalContainer} = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        {showModalContainer && <ModalContainer assetDocId={assetDocId} assetDBId={assetDBId} code={code} defaultValues={this.props.defaultValues} allAssetDetails={this.props.allAssetDetails} />}
      </div>
    )
}
```

There are many ways to do the same.

Comment: The modal appears only after the second time it is clicked, the first time the console ppppppppppppppp comes but not the popup modal.I believe it has got to do something with the state not getting set instantly after the first click.Could it be?

Answer (score 0):

onClick method doesn't do anything with the returned value, since your are returning the modal container from the `getAssetDocId` method, it won't work, you instead need to set a state and render the ModalContainer based on the state value

```
getAssetDocId(e) {
        var assetDocId = e.currentTarget.attributes['id'].value;
        var assetDBId = e.currentTarget.attributes['dbId'].value;
        var code = e.currentTarget.attributes['code'].value;
        this.setState({
            assetDocId, 
            assetDBId,
            code,
            showModal: true
        })
     }

render() {
    const { assetDocId, assetDBId, code, showModal } = this.state;
    return (
       <React.Fragment>
           <div className="card-overlay modal-trigger"  data-target="asset-detail" id={asset.docId} dbId={asset.dbId} code={asset.code} key={asset.docId} onClick={this.getAssetDocId}>
           {showModal && <ModalContainer assetDocId={assetDocId} assetDBId={assetDBId} code={code} defaultValues={this.props.defaultValues} allAssetDetails={this.props.allAssetDetails} />}
       </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: can you please explain as to what is the flaw in the current approach and why is the new one better,or is it just how it is done?

Comment: @SHIKHARSINGH when onClick triggers the component won't re-render in your case and also since you are using regular function this won't be available inside the function untill and unless you assign this to a local variable like self for eg. Because of these reasons child component isn't rendering

Comment: @SHIKHARSINGH, as I mentioned in my answer, the JSX returned to onClick isn't really processed by it and hence your content won't render, you need to render your content in the render function itself. The best way to do it is to have a boolean to show/hide the Component